# allow duplicate keys in dimension

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, olap, cube

I would need suggestion on this as I do not know SSAS much.

I have a customer dimension with -1 as customer key which means "Unknown". This customer dimension acts as Payee customer dimension in SSAS ( I created view to filter only payee customer based on payee flag).
Now in incoming transaction data, for PayeeCustomer, I am getting few customers that are payee and few which are not.

The one which are not payee is not customers in anyways, for those I have assigned -1(unknown) in fact.

So far good, Now the requirement is to track which are not payee and report to source.

I have created another dimension table and loaded the non Payee values.

In PayeeCustomer View that is used in SSAS, I have added union all to bring in non payee customer, for these customer keys will be -1.

So when processing PayeeCustomer dimension for sure I will be ending with duplicate error.

I need to see the data in the cube like below.

```
CustomerKey, AccountName
-1, Unknown
-1, UA8794
-1, FE6852
```

How do I achieve it or any alternate suggestion, Please help.

Comment: While you can set it to ignore duplicate errors, that is not advised. Perhaps make a composite key that uses the CustomerKey and another field to create a unique value for each customer.

Comment: Yes, thats the only way to do it to allow duplicates. But if you are joining this key with any measure, it requires join on all composite keys. So DB Fact table should have both column. In my case it was not, and I had to create one in fact and populate data into it. Thanks for reply.